# How do i sort data with ListJS by multiple status

Tags: javascript, listjs

I want sort by status ['ready','pending','in_progress','done']

The list should display

- data 1 -ready
- data 2 -ready
- data 10 -pending
- data 5 -in_progress
- data 3 -done

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you using json as data structure for your data:

```
var statusArr = ['ready','pending','in_progress','done']
var dataArr = [{data:"aa",status:"in_progress"},{data:"bb",status:"pending"},{data:"cc",status:"done"},{data:"dd",status:"ready"}]


dataArr.sort((a, b) => statusArr.indexOf(a.status) - statusArr.indexOf(b.status));

console.log(dataArr)
```

this will result:

```
[
  { data: 'dd', status: 'ready' },
  { data: 'bb', status: 'pending' },
  { data: 'aa', status: 'in_progress' },
  { data: 'cc', status: 'done' }
]
```

Comment: did it work with third party listJs?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a JS objects using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which allows for quick lookups in constant time `O(1)` which holds the priority or sort position assigned to a value.

Then using that object you can easily lookup the sort position and sort accordingly. The overall runtime of the algorithm is `O(n)`. If you use something like `indexOf()` the runtime will be `O(n²)` since `indexOf()` does a linear search.

I am using the relatively new [`toSorted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) instead of the older [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method here since [`toSorted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) returns a new array and is therefore the [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) option, which should generally be preferred. [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted#browser_compatibility) is not especially good as of now, so by reason of that you might need to fallback to [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
const statuses = ['ready', 'pending', 'in_progress', 'done'];
const unsorted = [{
  data: "aa",
  status: "in_progress"
}, {
  data: "bb",
  status: "pending"
}, {
  data: "cc",
  status: "done"
}, {
  data: "dd",
  status: "ready"
}]

const statusPriorities = statuses.reduce((all, cur, i) => (all[cur] = i, all), {});


// use sort() to manipulate the original array (mutable variant)
// we use the immutable variant here
const sorted = unsorted.toSorted((a, b) => statuses[a.status] - statuses[b.status]);
console.log(sorted);
```